# Visual Svn Server: How to restrict edit by specified IP Address

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, svn-server, visualsvn-server

I want to enable only a specific IPAddess to edit (add, delete, update...) my visual svn server, but all others IPAddess must be able to read...

I believe it is necessary a change like this in the file `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd-custom.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Location /svn>
    # write access
    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      Order deny,allow
      deny from all
      Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    </LimitExcept>
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but do not know well visual svn server. what is the right way?

`Visual SVN Server 3.2 x64` is installed in `Windows 2008 R2 Server x64`

**UPDATE from VisualSvn support**

> Such feature is not available in VisualSVN Server 3.2 out-of-the-box,
>   however we consider the possibility to implement it in future
>   versions. [...] Generally speaking, it is possible to implement
>   IP-based restrictions via modifying httpd-custom.conf file, however we
>   strongly discourage to take this approach. VisualSVN Server has
>   "SVNPathAuthz short_circuit" option enabled, which dramatically
>   improves authorization performance. The option has a limitation,
>   though: server configuration mustn't rely on other authorization
>   modules such as "authz_host_module" (which is responsible for IP-based
>   checks), otherwise you will encounter unexpected behavior with
>   authorization. On the other hand, if you disable "short_circuit" you
>   will definitely notice performance degradation when running
>   authorization-intensive operations against you repositories (such as
>   running `svn log`, `svn checkout`, `svn export, etc or running a
>   graphical repository browser such as the one TortoiseSVN client
>   provides)